# Learning how to code advanced Windows malware

Tags: windows, malware, programming

I often see advanced malware on Windows platform - rootkits, bootkits, web injection, formgrabbers, injecting into other processes etc...

Some of this looks so difficult to understand. If you knew the inside and outside of the operating system, it would probably be a better career working for Microsoft...

Aside from getting good at Win32 development, what else would be required to learn this? I would guess understanding Windows internals.

Comment: "Aside from getting good at Win32 development" is quite broad. ;-)
I would suggest to learn how malware works; there are several examples of malware analysis which could *inspire* you.  Good foundations of communication, encryption and system internals would give you a good head start.

Answer (score 2):

Would you like a manual on how to make rootkits, bootkits, web injections, formgrabbers and inject into other processes?

It's probably not all gonna fit here. I would suggest narrowing your question so we can provide you with technical information.

Otherwise, getting good at the internals of the OS you're trying to infect really is the only advice we can give. https://www.reddit.com/r/Malware/ is also a very broad resource where you can dig around all types of malware analysis blogposts.